# Dual boot with Linux and Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, ssd, grub

Currently I have Windows 10 installed on a SSD; now I'm about to add a new SSD and I want to install Ubuntu Mate on it.

As far I understand the Grub will make a dual boot in this second SSD so the BIOS must set it up to boot with this second SSD. If I remove the Linux SSD the BIOS will boot with the first SSD and Windows 10 will not notice any difference.

I'm right? The Grub doesn't change the first SSD?

What I want is if both SSD are connected the GRUB will take control and if only the current SSD is connected Windows 10 boot as is doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is the boot partition, be it BIOS or UEFI, the boot partition
is one and only one. After booting from it, the boot software will
evoke the bootloader for the chosen operating system from its
installed disk.

Note that a UEFI computer does not need Grub to be installed, as the
multi-boot is done by the firmware, using the EFI partition.

So the answer is that only the non-boot disk can be removed.

Comment: How do I know if the boot is UEFI or BIOS? I don't want to change the Windows 10 boot, so I think I will install Linux without the Windows SSD connected and will plug the proper disk before turn on the PC.

Comment: Yes, that will work of course. As requested, to find out your boot type, run "System Information" and look at "BIOS Mode", which will be Legacy or UEFI.

Comment: Thanks, it seems is running in UEFI mode.